# How to get all converters and formatters that register in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I want to the behaviors of serialization and deserializion consistent in the Spring ConverterSPI/Formatter and JsonHttpMessageConverter/XmlHttpMessageConverter.

So,i try to register all converters in Spring ConverterSPI to global configuration JsonHttpMessageConverter/XmlHttpMessageConverter provides.

So how to get all converters and formatters that register in spring?

I want to get converters and formatters condition by target type is String or Number class.

And most serious problem is that some formatters based on field annotation such as @NumberFormat.
For example,org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory based on @NumberFormat to create Formatter.

This is also the useful formatter of spring.It is not only related to class type, but also with field annotation. 
I need get Relevant information for this part of formatters.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can autowired them via interface:

```
@Autowired
private List<HttpMessageConverter> converters;

@Autowired
private List<Formatter> formatters;
```

Comment: This is my alternative.Because some converters may be registered to FormatterRegistry,but not registered to container.And the most serious problem is that some formatters based on FieldAnnotation. I need get Relevant information for this part of formatters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-

So something like.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(XmlHttpMessageConverter.class);
        applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Formatter.class);
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to do something with the return values of the getBeansOfType.

I'm not sure what you mean by "registered by fieldannotations" that shouldn't matter when you're querying spring for what beans it has.

Comment: Some formatters based on field annotation such as @NumberFormat.So it is not enough to get target type and source type of formatter only.

Comment: @caotc I'm very confused. No matter how you register a bean it still ends up in the spring context.

Comment: For example,org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory based on @NumberFormat to create Formatter.This is also the useful formatter of spring.It is not only related to class type, but also with field annotation.